# How to get medical insurance for a Singapore layover?

Tags: transit, health, insurance, singapore

I am travelling to Australia from Europe, with a layover in Singapore on both legs of my travel. On my outbound trip, I have a 15-hour layover and I will surely visit the city; on the return, I have ca. 6 hours and I may decide not to leave the airport.

I am worried about medical assistance in case of emergencies during these two layovers (during my stay in Australia I am covered by a reciprocity agreement between my homeland and Australia).

I find various insurance options about travel medical assistance, but they insist on covering the whole trip and not just an isolated day or two which are a small part of it. So, my questions are:

1. Am I going to need a medical insurance for a layover in Singapore? Even if I don't leave the airport? Or are medical emergencies covered for free by the state health services?
2. If the answer is yes, where can I buy medical insurance for such a short period of time? Directly through a Singapore company? Or maybe is there a company selling travel assistance in Europe that is flexible enough to cover only a short part of a trip?

Comment: This depends on your country, your medical insurance, and eventually your travel insurance. There is no way to answer in a general way,

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Assume I have no other medical insurance and no travel insurance.

Comment: you are an European, so you have one. But from your answer, I assume you are Italian, so you should check if your state insurance cover also out of Europe countries (and for how much time).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: He says he has checked this and found that it doesn't.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi As Henning says. The Italian insurance covers Australia, which is my main destination, but not Singapore, where my layovers are. (By the way, if I am not mistaken "you are European so you have one" is not as automatic as you think: medical insurance is tied to one's place of employment, as far as I know.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, you say you can not get a travel insurance for just the days in transit, have you walked in at a place where they sell travel insurances to see whether they can adjust the information when they fill it out there? (Where I live you tell them the departure date and the number of days you travel, in which case I would get an insurance from leaving home to arriving in Australia and a second one for the way back, again just '3' days.)

Comment: @Willeke Walked no, phoned yes, to three providers in my country, and they all only cover full trips. I could get insurance for the whole trip, but it seems a waste since it's a long-ish work trip.

Comment: Can you convince them your 'full trip' is 3 days?

Comment: @Willeke This will work great until he needs to claim for an expensive medical treatment, at which point the insurer will investigate and declare that he lied to them, and is not covered.

Comment: Can you clarify why you're worried about medical insurance? Do you have a chronic condition that might need care? Or are you worried about random accidents and not being able to get care for them?

Comment: @AzorAhai I am in good health (I hope at least). I only worry about accidents / medical emergencies.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Does your work provide medical insurance on business trips?  In some countries, like the US, the employer may be responsible for injuries and illness on business travel, so provision of insurance is common.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni [See this](https://www.unipi.it/index.php/amministrazione/item/4128-polizza-infortuni-a-favore-degli-studenti-e-dei-dipendenti). You definitely want to contact the insurance people at your work and have them tell you what to do.

Comment: @user71659 Thanks for the helpful stalking work. ;) They claimed that I have to worry about travel medical assistance, and then it will get reimbursed. But I will definitely point them at this document and ask.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni No problem lol. It is apparently common for the university to purchase blanket travel insurance in the English speaking world at least ([US](https://global.psu.edu/article/international-insurance-university-affiliated-travel), [UK](http://www.admin.ox.ac.uk/finance/insurance/travel/), [AU](http://www.utas.edu.au/finance/travel/plan-travel/insurance)). I'm pretty sure the reason is that in these systems, insurance can't be directly charged to research funds, it has to come from overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of travel insurers, eg. World Nomads (no affiliation), will quite happily sell you medical insurance per day and per country, so if you want peace of mind you could buy two separate single days of coverage from them.

That said, insurance makes the most sense when you can't cover the cost of catastrophe, but in Singapore the public medical system is both **excellent** and **very affordable**, even at the unsubsidized rates paid by non-residents.  For example, if you're hospitalized for a week due to heart failure, even at the high end of the scale you're looking at a bill of only $3500 or so: https://www.moh.gov.sg/cost-financing/bill-estimator/total-hospital-bills/HospitalBillsDetail/F62A

...which compares pretty favorably with the 6 figure bills you'd be looking at in the US.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful information. I will definitely ask World Nomads for clarifications, but it seems like their form asks explicitly for the full duration of my trip: * Tell us your travel details* -- *Start date* -- *End date*.

Comment: @FedoricoPoloni That's the dates of coverage you want, which doesn't have to be the whole trip.

Comment: You may read it that way, but it clearly states "tell us your travel details". They can later claim that my insurance is invalid because I entered incorrect details. (See also [MJeffryes comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118766/how-to-get-medical-insurance-for-a-singapore-layover/118808?noredirect=1#comment291266_118766) to another answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you're unprepared to buy for the duration of your trip (which may still be wise, if there are restrictions on the reciprocity between Australia and your homeland), the easiest option may be to get a credit card that provides travel medical coverage.  This will generally cover trips up to a certain duration, so the length of your trip will matter.  The cards usually include other benefits that are useful to travelers too, such as baggage coverage.

Even if you could buy the short-term coverage, there would be a minimum premium for each burst of time you need it, so you might pay as much for a single day as you would pay for a week or two of coverage; it may not be as cost-ineffective to insure the whole trip as you think.

Bear in mind, too, that if your aircraft stops in another country because of your medical emergency, it is possible you could end up in another country than these completely unplanned, as well, and need medical insurance there, too.  This is also possible if your aircraft stops for mechanical issues or for any other reason.

Comment: An other reason to buy coverage for the whole trip is repatriation which is not usually part of reciprocity medical care.